# PHP Mailer Multiple email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a form in my website. When the user fills out the form, I want an email to be sent to me with data entered in the form and also a thank you email for the person filling the form.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    function sendEmail($subject, $body) {
        require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // does tls works with port 25
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com'; // is this the correct 
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->Username = "noreply@domain.org";
        $mail->Password = "mypassword";
        $mail->SetFrom("noreply@domain.org");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAddress('data@domain.org');

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $mail->ErrorInfo;
            echo "<script>alert('Error Occured sending the enquiry. Please try again')</script>";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>window.location.href='http://domain.com/index.html'</script>";
        }
    }

    ?>

    <?php
    function sendEmail($subject, $body) {
        require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // does tls works with port 25
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com'; // is this the correct 
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->Username = "noreply@domain.org";
        $mail->Password = "mypassword";
        $mail->SetFrom("noreply@domain.org");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $body;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAddress(''.$_POST['emailAddr'].''); // **
```

emailAddr is the name for email field in the form and I wish to send email to this email address.

```
        $mail->Subject = 'Thank you for contacting Domain';
        $mail->Body    = 'Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been received and will be processed as soon as possible.';

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $mail->ErrorInfo;
            echo "<script>alert('Error Occured sending the enquiry. Please try again')</script>";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>window.location.href='http://domain.com/index.html'</script>";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: $mail->AddAddress($_POST['emailAddr']);  no need qotes

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Thanks.

Comment: Set `SMTPDebug` to something like `3` and copy paste the results